# Sort list of dictionaries with natsort to obtain natural sort order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, natsort

I'm looking for a method to sort a list of dicts to obtain a 'natural sort order'. I have found the module `natsort`, but apparantly I'm not using it right to get the list of dictionaries correctly sorted. Can anyone help to find my error?

Here's my code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import natsort

# Example list an dict
list = ['13h', '1h', '3h']
dict = [{'a': '13h', 'b': 3}, {'a': '1h', 'b': 1}, {'a': '3h', 'b': 0}]

# Sort the list
natsort.natsorted(list, key=lambda y: y.lower())

# Sort the dict
# Later I also want to sort on several keys, therefore the itemgetter
sorted(dic, key=itemgetter(*['a']))
```

Comment: Have you tried - `natsort.natsorted(dic, key=itemgetter(*['a']))` ?

Comment: No. Lol, it works. That means I already had the answer :/

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `key=lambda y: y.lower()` on the first pass?  It looks like your data is already lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can substitute `natsort.natsorted` instead of `sorted()` in your code and it should work. Example -

```
natsort.natsorted(dic, key=itemgetter(*['a']))
```

This should return a list of dictionaries, where the elements are sorted based on value of key `'a'` .

Comment: I was looking everywhere for this, 5 years on :)